# jQuery: Priority on Events registered via css-selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I try to build a small, but flexible click-handler for links like delete. This handler should be register via css-class-selector.

```
<a href="#" class="confirm-delete">delete</a>

<script>
$(document).on('click', '.confirm-delete', function() {
    return window.confirm('sure?');
});
</script>
```

That works fine so far. But the real action should also register via selector.

```
<a href="confirm-delete delete">delete</a>
```

Now I got a little problem with the event-priority, because the delete-event will be handled first and the confirm later.

Is there a way to get more control in which order the events will be triggered?

Comment: How did you get that to work when the selector in the event handler is for a class, and there seems to be no class in the anchor tag?

Comment: Your anchor tag should be `<a href="#" class="confirm-delete">delete</a>`

Comment: And how is your delete event look like?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code. The real code is more complex, so I just typed the important stuff.

Comment: can you get a jsfiddle demo running?

Comment: @Joseph: http://jsfiddle.net/Env2X/
I found out, that the order is important in what the events get registered. In my case I cannot controll it, because there are a lot of elements added later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the confirm to run before your delete action, try this:

```
<a href="#" class="confirm-delete">delete</a>

<script >
  $(document).on('click', '.confirm-delete', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (window.confirm('sure?')) {
          // do your action here
      }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is the coupling I try to avoid. ;-)